# Is there an array method in Ruby for "must include at least one of these but can't include anything else"?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm doing an exercise where the input is an array. I need a way to return `false` if the array contains anything other than the strings 'n', 's', 'e' and 'w' or if the array does not contain any of the strings 'n', 's', 'e' and 'w'. Is there a pre-defined method for this?

If not, how can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a built-in method you could use. If `arr` is your array, you could do the following.

```
directions = ['n', 's', 'e', 'w']

arr.any? && (arr-directions).empty?
```

Some examples:

```
arr = ['n', 's', 'n']
arr.any? && (arr-directions).empty?
  #=> true

arr = ['n', 's', 'f']
arr.any? && (arr-directions).empty?
    #=> false

arr = ['f', 'g']
arr.any? && (arr-directions).empty?
  #=> false

arr = []
arr.any? && (arr-directions).empty?
  #=> false
```

Comment: This seems to be the simplest answer thanks. I ended up using SYoung82's answer only because i already had a block with "if" statements and just added it on. Is that not smart? I'm pretty new to ruby.

Comment: I can't say if that's smart or not. Some Rubiests will make minimal changes to get their code working; others, if they think of a better way of doing something, will rip out all their old code. It may also depend on time pressures.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any built-in function as far as I'm aware. You could do something like below or try the [`include?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/include%3F) method on your array.

```
array.each do |element|
  if element != 'n' && element != 's' && element != 'e' && element != 'w'
    return false
  end
end

return true
```

This should go through each element of the array and compare each element to 'n','s','e', and 'w'. If it finds something that doesn't match, it returns false. If it makes it all the way through without finding anything out of the ordinary, it returns true. You may want to check for an empty string at the beginning also.

Comment: @ichi_the_killer bear in mind that as it stands, this solution returns `true` for an empty array `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [grep](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) and [grep_v](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v) with regex:

```
def news? arr
  r = /[news]/
  !arr.grep(r).empty? && arr.grep_v(r).empty?
end
```

Using Cary's tests (albeit slightly modified):

```
news? ['n', 's', 'n'] #=> true
news? ['n', 's', 'f'] #=> false
news? ['f', 'g', 'h'] #=> false
news? []              #=> false
```

Comment: I've never used grep or grep_v I'll have to remember them thanks